# C# Windows Forms to Blend VS2013

Tags: c#, blend

I recently downloaded VS 2013 Pro and have been reading about Blend. I currently have a C# Windows Forms application that doesn't look visually appealing at all. Is it possible, in any manner, to convert the UI from WF to Blend on the surface level?

EDIT: I haven't finished installing VS 2013 Pro so I'm asking to avoid wasting time in case it isn't possible.

Comment: @SLaks Is it possible to convert just the aesthetics from WinForms to Blend? Something similar to changing a "texture pack"?

Comment: I did a quick search and found this, but I've never tried it so I don't know how effective it is or if it works at all. https://wf2wpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Didn't seem to work but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Blend then you need your UI to be built in XAML.

Unfortunately I am unable to find any converters. XAML is quite different to WinForms.

If you want to use Blend, create a WPF project and then rewrite your UI code.

The philosophy behind XAML is also different, you are likely to use databinding and MVVM.

If you don't have any knowledge of XAML, initially learn the principles.

Either rewrite the app or use WinForms.